# hello! - a country's vacation

Tags: knowledge, story, geography

***Finally.***

The U.N., benevolent and all-knowing master he is, has decided to let you take a vacation...

*But he's letting UNESCO decide for yo*- speak of the devil.

"Hullo, Kossie!"

"I told you. **Don't call me "Kossie" or I'll send you to the shadow realm.**"

"Whoa there, *Koss*. Here's the list:

**Rio de Janeiro, Kampala, Tbilisi, Amundsen-Scott, Riyadh, Windhoek, (day-to-day) Dublin, Otjiwarongo, Artigas, Macau, São Tomé, Buenos Aires. Choose from your three options, I think you’ll enjoy them! :)))**”

A smiley face was written on the top. Really? Could I at LEAST know my options?

Comment: WE’RE BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACK with another story with our hero, Kosovo (affectionately referred to as Koss or Kossie)!

Answer (score 3):

**Partial Answer**

I have at least pulled out three place names from the information given by UNESCO but have not used all the place names so I must be missing something.

First of all

> Identify the countries to which each place listed lies and obtain the corresponding two-letter [ISO 3166-1_alpha-2 country codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) as follows:
>  Rio de Janeiro -> Brazil -> **BR**
>  Kampala -> Uganda ->  **UG**
>  Tbilisi -> Georgia -> **GE**
>  Amundsen-Scott -> USA -> **US**
>  Riyadh ->  Saudi Arabia -> **SA**
>  Windhoek -> Namibia -> **NA**
>  Dublin -> Ireland -> **IE**
>  Otjiwarongo -> Namibia -> **NA**
>  Artigas ->  Uruguay -> **UY**
>  Macau -> Macao -> **MO**
>  Sao Tome -> Sao Tome and Principe -> **ST**
>  Buenos Aires -> Argentina -> **AR**

Then

> Reading the two letter codes in groups of three gives us [BRUGGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruges), [USSANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ussana), IENAUY, [MOSTAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostar)
>  Three of these are well known place names and may correspond to the three options. However, I don't know what to do with **IENAUY**

Comment: Close, but UNESCO hates leaving things nullispaced. Could you explain how he added spaces? (also, one of those options is incorrect)